# Why does Blazor not re-render when object is removed from list?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

When I have the following piece of code, I would expect Blazor to re-render the unordered list once I click an item. However, despite the item getting removed from memory, Blazor does not rerender anything in the UI. I can solve this by calling StateHasChanged(), but I think there should be a better solution. Can anyone help me out? Your help is appreciated!

```
@page "/"

<ul>
    @foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        <li onclick="@(() => RemoveItem(item))">@item.Value</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {

    List<Item> items = new() { 
        new Item() { Value = 1 },
        new Item() { Value = 2 },
        new Item() { Value = 3 },
    };

    void RemoveItem(Item item)
    {
        items.Remove(item);
    }

    class Item
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the @ in front of `onclick`? This code seems to work without StateHasChanged(). https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QRkewEPm45BO1Ga456

Comment: @Axekan Seems that solves it here indeed. The original code that this was serving as a minimal failing example for is still not working though, so I'll try to dig into the problem a little more.

Comment: You can (should) delete this then.

Comment: Doesn't Blazor depend on `INotifyPropertyChanged`? If so, then you should use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` - and that collection must be long-lived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```cs
@page "/"

<ul>
    @foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        <li @onclick="() => RemoveItem(item)">@item.Value</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {

    List<Item> items = new() {
        new Item() { Value = 1 },
        new Item() { Value = 2 },
        new Item() { Value = 3 },
    };

    private async Task RemoveItem(Item item)
    {
        // Your probably trying to do something async here
        // So lets fake an async call
        await Task.Delay(100);
        items.Remove(item);
    }

    class Item
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Your probably trying to do something async here"_ - if that's the case then shouldn't you add an `await` inside `<li @onclick="async () => await RemoveItem(item)">`, no?

Comment: @Dai - No.  If `RemoveItem` returns a `Task`, your creating a double `Task` wrapper i.e. wrapping a `Task` in a `Task` - wasting resources.  However, in this case `RemoveItem` returns a void, so wrapping it in another `Task` will make no difference.  You can't `await` a `void`.  The `ComponentBase` handler will hammer on through to completion if `RemoveItem` yields, as there's nothing to await in the `ComponentBase` implementation of `IHandleEvent`.  Any updates you do after the yield will not get captured in the component render.